# How can I fix button position for different Device Size Using CGRectMake

Tags: ios, uibutton, cgrectmake

I have created a `UIButton` using `CGRectMake`, This button looks perfect for the portrait mode and remains fixed in the same place as I wanted. But, when I change the orientation to landscape button position changes. How can I fix this?

```
 UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(216, 130, 64, 30)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourEditButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-details.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

NSLog(@"sender.tag cell is%ld ",(long)button.tag);
```

Comment: Use auto layout instead of using CGRectMake anyways, i will still provide you a way to use CGRectMake

Comment: @StanlyMoses  any help is appreciated

Comment: you should not not need to give static frame to button , you can use autolayout or set frame relative to other controls make it dynamic

Comment: @MikeAlter thats what i want to do, i want to make it dynamic but don't know how

Comment: please review my answer. Try autolayout bro. Its simple. You can easily use autolayout and target various devices in a easy way.

Comment: resizing buttons using cgrectmake is not an effecient way because it will be hard if you are making changes to design. so use autolayout.

Comment: @Stanly Moses but how can i use auto layout  for the button i have created this way as i created above using CGRectMake

Comment: Just remove the above code. Put the button in your viewcontroller of storyboard and apply autolayout. Create a new referencing outlet from the button that you have created and access it later.

Comment: @Stanly Moses dude i have tried that but if i create a button using storyboard and create a outlet to use it further in action of that button itself it gives me error that the repeating content cannot be attached to the same thing.

Comment: create a touchupinside action from the storyboard itself bro.

Comment: are you using buttons within tableview cells?

Comment: @StanlyMoses  first of all thanks a ton man for the help. But i am creating touchupinside action only but still it says can't attach the repeating content to the same thing. and the above button i am using is in tableView cell so i have to use  indexPath and its tag also. So at that time i get problem if i use the storyboard button and outlet of it and use it in the action of itself.

Comment: @StanlyMoses yes i am using it in tableView Cell

Comment: mention not... Are you using static tableview cells or custom tableview cells? because if you are using static tableview cells , you might get this errror

Comment: @StanlyMoses no it is not static it is custom table view cell

Comment: then are you trying to create outlet in your cutom  tableviewcell class or in the class that you are implementing the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: repeating content cannot be attached to the same thing will be fired if you are inflating the same content in the same tableview cell multiple times. so check your code for the same

Comment: @StanlyMoses i am creating outlet in the class i am implementing cellForRow

Comment: thats the problem. Create outlet in your custom class and access it within cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: is it working by now bro?

Answer (score 1):

Define macros like the following,

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

In your xib, drag button and put it inside the xib. Resize the screen width and height of xib and position your button for various of various screen width and height.Note down the width , height, x,y positions for various screen sizes and then use them in your following code

```
 UIButton *button;
//use x,y,width,height values relative to the values you have noted previously and  pass them in  the following parameters

       if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
        {
         button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];   
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
        {
         button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];   

        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
        {
         button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];   

        }


[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourEditButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-details.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

NSLog(@"sender.tag cell is%ld ",(long)button.tag);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. should i do the same for the iPads also.

Answer (score 0):

Apply vertical/horizontal constraints to the button set at position 0. Then click the constraints and adjust the multiplier (in the range 0-2) which places the view proportionally down/across the superview.